# While loop data not appending to list outside of while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I am trying to scrape data, write it to a pd series then go into a while loop for the remaining pages of the website appending to the original series (located outside of the while loop) after each iteration. I'm not sure why this isn't working. Here's where I'm stuck:

```
current_url = 'https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=hvac&geo_location_terms=97080'

def get_data_run(current_url):
    company_names1 = get_company_name(current_url)
    print(company_names1) #1
    page = 1
    max_page = 3
    company_names1 = paginate(current_url, page, max_page, company_names1)
    print(company_names1) #2



def paginate(current_url, page, max_page, company_names1):
    while (page <= max_page):
            new_url = current_url + f"&page={page}"
            print(new_url)
            company_names = get_company_name(new_url)
            company_names1.append(company_names)
            print(company_names) #3
            print(company_names1) #4
            
            page +=1
            if page == max_page:
                return company_names1

def get_company_name(url):
    company_names = []
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
    box = list(soup.findAll("div", {"class": "result"}))
    for i in range(len(box)):
        try:
            company_names.append(box[i].find("a", {"class": "business-name"}).text.strip())
        except Exception:
            company_names.append("null")
        else: 
            continue
    company_names = pd.Series(company_names, dtype='string')
    return company_names


get_data_run(current_url)
```

I've labeled the different prints and all of the prints of `company_names1` and `company_names` and each time `company_names1` it prints the same series of companies even after appending `company_names` inside the while loop. The thing I can't understand is that when I print `company_names` (#3) it prints the next page of company names. I don't understand why its not appending inside the while loop then why it's not returning outside of the function successfully and printing the combined series in the #2 print. Thanks!

UPDATE:
Here is some sample output:

when I print #3:

```
(pyfinance) justinbenfit@MacBook-Pro-3 yellowpages_scrape % /usr/local/anaconda3/envs/pyfinance/bin/python /Users/justinbenfit/Desktop/yellowpages_scrape/test.py
0             Honke Heating & Air Conditioning
1                   Climate Kings Heating & Ac
2                  Mike's Truck & Auto Service
3          One Hour Heating & Air Conditioning
4                 Morgan Heating & Cooling Inc
5       Rnr Heating Venting & Air Conditioning
6                           Universal HVAC Inc
7                                   Mr Furnace
8                Affordable Excellence Heating
9                           Green Air Products
10                        David Eugene Neketin
11                  Century Heating & Air Cond
12                            Appliance Wizard
13             Precision Energy Solutions Inc.
14      Portland Heating & Air Conditioning Co
15                                         Mhc
16     American Pride Heating and Cooling, LLC
17                            Tri Star Western
18                 Comfort Zone Heat & Air Inc
19                          Don's Air-Care Inc
20                   Chuck's Heating & Cooling
21    Mt. Hood Heating Cooling & Refrigeration
22                   Chuck's Heating & Cooling
23                                 Mr. Furnace
24                  America's Same Day Service
25         Arctic Commercial Refrigeration LLC
26                          Apex Refrigeration
27        Ben's Heating & Air Conditioning LLC
28                       David's Appliance Inc
29                   Wolcott Heating & Cooling
dtype: string
0                                              Air-Trix
1                                      Johnstone Supply
2                            Buss Heating & Cooling Inc
3                                     The Heat Exchange
4                   Hoodview Heating & Air Conditioning
5                Loomis Heating Cooling & Refrigeration
6                       All About Air Heating & Cooling
7                                        Hanson Heating
8                              Sparks Heating & Cooling
9                              Interior Comfort Systems
10                              P D X Heating & Cooling
11                                      Apcom Power Inc
12                                     Area Heating Inc
13    Four Seasons Heating Air Conditioning & Servic...
14                                  Perfect Climate Inc
15                           Combustion Consultants Inc
16                            Classic Heat Source, Inc.
17                               Multnomah Heating, Inc
18     Apollo Plumbing, Heating & Air Conditioning - OR
19                             Art's Furnace & Air Cond
20                                      Kurchel Heating
21                               P & O Construction Inc
22                                Systems Management NW
23                                   Bridgetown Heating
24             Amana Heating & Air Conditioning Systems
25                                         QualitySmith
26                                   Wilbert Jr, Wilson
27                 Faith Heating & Air Conditioning Inc
28    Northwest Commercial Heating & Air Conditionin...
29                                     Heat Master Corp
dtype: string
```

when I print #1, #2, and #4

```
0             Honke Heating & Air Conditioning
1                   Climate Kings Heating & Ac
2                  Mike's Truck & Auto Service
3          One Hour Heating & Air Conditioning
4                 Morgan Heating & Cooling Inc
5       Rnr Heating Venting & Air Conditioning
6                           Universal HVAC Inc
7                                   Mr Furnace
8                Affordable Excellence Heating
9                           Green Air Products
10                        David Eugene Neketin
11                  Century Heating & Air Cond
12                            Appliance Wizard
13             Precision Energy Solutions Inc.
14      Portland Heating & Air Conditioning Co
15                                         Mhc
16     American Pride Heating and Cooling, LLC
17                            Tri Star Western
18                 Comfort Zone Heat & Air Inc
19                          Don's Air-Care Inc
20                   Chuck's Heating & Cooling
21                   Chuck's Heating & Cooling
22                                 Mr. Furnace
23    Mt. Hood Heating Cooling & Refrigeration
24                  America's Same Day Service
25         Arctic Commercial Refrigeration LLC
26                          Apex Refrigeration
27        Ben's Heating & Air Conditioning LLC
28                       David's Appliance Inc
29                   Wolcott Heating & Cooling
dtype: string
```

Comment: Can you show a sample output (as properly formatted text in the question)?

Comment: just write `company_names1 = company_names1.append(company_names)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're treating `pd.Series` as a `list`, but the former are immutable while the later are mutable. This means, appending data to a list works like this:

```
lst = [1,2,3]
lst.append(4)
print(lst)
# [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

The object changes without having to explicitly assign it. If you do the same with `Series`, this happens:

```
series = pd.Series([1,2,3])
series.append(pd.Series([4]))
print(series)
```

The output is:

```
0    1
1    2
2    3
dtype: int64
```

So, to update a Series, you have to replace the original object or create a new one. If there's no assignment it won't be stored in memory:

```
series = pd.Series([1,2,3])
series = series.append(pd.Series([4]))
print(series)
```

Output:

```
0    1
1    2
2    3
0    4
dtype: int64
```

In the case of your problem it lies in the `paginate` function, you should change this line:

```
company_names1.append(company_names)
```

to:

```
company_names1 = company_names1.append(company_names)
```

And everything should work

Comment: Thank you @Juan C! It appears to have worked with one exception. when I print number #3 it gives me the first 29 results then, in the same series, it starts the index over at 0 then shows the first 29 results again as well as the second page results but each new series that was appended keeps it's original indexing starting over at 0. Would you recommend just appending everything to a list then converting to a series after the pagination?

Comment: I think that would be better. Else you can add `.reset_index()` to your function call  like this:
`company_names1 = paginate(current_url, page, max_page, company_names1).reset_index()`